# Grep for specified words in .txt returns unwanted lines

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to search a list of filenames to contain this information in one line: 
`<filename>` `S1A_` `GRDH`. However when I use the command below I get lines that don't include this information in addition to the lines I want

`$ grep "=\"filename"\>" | grep "\S1A_\" | grep "GRDH" fileout >> s1_gg.txt`

sample of fileout:

```
    <title>S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161113T055721_20161113T055746_002936_004FB6_2A93</title>
    <link href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('f97e7088-3d9d-4f88-bc8b-23027dbeb964')/$value"/>
    <link rel="alternative" href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('f97e7088-3d9d-4f88-bc8b-23027dbeb964')/"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('f97e7088-3d9d-4f88-bc8b-23027dbeb964')/Products('Quicklook')/$value"/>
    <id>f97e7088-3d9d-4f88-bc8b-23027dbeb964</id>
    <summary>Date: 2016-11-13T05:57:21.177Z, Instrument: SAR-C SAR, Mode: VV VH, Satellite: Sentinel-1, Size: 1.66 GB</summary>
    <str name="uuid">f97e7088-3d9d-4f88-bc8b-23027dbeb964</str>
    <str name="acquisitiontype">NOMINAL</str>
    <str name="filename">S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161113T055721_20161113T055746_002936_004FB6_2A93.SAFE</str>
    <str name="gmlfootprint">&lt;gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"&gt;
       &lt;gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;
          &lt;gml:LinearRing&gt;
             &lt;gml:coordinates&gt;51.329529,5.606034 51.745312,1.813976 53.240158,2.187638 52.821747,6.108649 51.329529,5.606034&lt;/gml:coordinates&gt;
          &lt;/gml:LinearRing&gt;
       &lt;/gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;
    &lt;/gml:Polygon&gt;</str>
    <str name="format">SAFE</str>
    <str name="identifier">S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161113T055721_20161113T055746_002936_004FB6_2A93</str>
    <date name="ingestiondate">2016-11-13T12:50:19.53Z</date>
    <str name="instrumentshortname">SAR-C SAR</str>
    <str name="sensoroperationalmode">IW</str>
    <str name="instrumentname">Synthetic Aperture Radar (C-band)</str>
    <str name="swathidentifier">IW</str>
    <str name="footprint">POLYGON ((5.606034 51.329529,1.813976 51.745312,2.187638 53.240158,6.108649 52.821747,5.606034 51.329529))</str>
    <int name="missiondatatakeid">20406</int>
    <str name="platformidentifier">2016-025A</str>
    <int name="orbitnumber">2936</int>
    <int name="lastorbitnumber">2936</int>
    <str name="orbitdirection">DESCENDING</str>
    <str name="polarisationmode">VV VH</str>
    <str name="productclass">S</str>
    <str name="producttype">GRD</str>
    <int name="relativeorbitnumber">110</int>
    <int name="lastrelativeorbitnumber">110</int>
    <str name="platformname">Sentinel-1</str>
    <date name="beginposition">2016-11-13T05:57:21.177Z</date>
    <date name="endposition">2016-11-13T05:57:46.175Z</date>
    <str name="size">1.66 GB</str>
    <int name="slicenumber">15</int>
    <str name="status">ARCHIVED</str>
    <bool name="processed">false</bool>
    </entry>
<title>S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF</title>
<link href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c0b070a1-cf49-4cd8-b72f-47003cf7a048')/$value"/>
<link rel="alternative" href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c0b070a1-cf49-4cd8-b72f-47003cf7a048')/"/>
<link rel="icon" href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('c0b070a1-cf49-4cd8-b72f-47003cf7a048')/Products('Quicklook')/$value"/>
<id>c0b070a1-cf49-4cd8-b72f-47003cf7a048</id>
<summary>Date: 2016-11-12T06:06:23.524Z, Instrument: SAR-C SAR, Mode: VV VH, Satellite: Sentinel-1, Size: 1.64 GB</summary>
<str name="uuid">c0b070a1-cf49-4cd8-b72f-47003cf7a048</str>
<str name="acquisitiontype">NOMINAL</str>
<str name="filename">S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF.SAFE</str>
<str name="gmlfootprint">&lt;gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"&gt;
   &lt;gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;
      &lt;gml:LinearRing&gt;
         &lt;gml:coordinates&gt;50.937958,3.404580 51.348900,-0.315099 52.843983,0.056133 52.430630,3.900550 50.937958,3.404580&lt;/gml:coordinates&gt;
      &lt;/gml:LinearRing&gt;
   &lt;/gml:outerBoundaryIs&gt;
&lt;/gml:Polygon&gt;</str>
<str name="format">SAFE</str>
<str name="identifier">S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF</str>
<date name="ingestiondate">2016-11-12T13:18:49.099Z</date>
<str name="instrumentshortname">SAR-C SAR</str>
<str name="sensoroperationalmode">IW</str>
<str name="instrumentname">Synthetic Aperture Radar (C-band)</str>
<str name="swathidentifier">IW</str>
<str name="footprint">POLYGON ((3.404580 50.937958,-0.315099 51.348900,0.056133 52.843983,3.900550 52.430630,3.404580 50.937958))</str>
<int name="missiondatatakeid">91675</int>
<str name="platformidentifier">2014-016A</str>
<int name="orbitnumber">13905</int>
<int name="lastorbitnumber">13905</int>
<str name="orbitdirection">DESCENDING</str>
<str name="polarisationmode">VV VH</str>
<str name="productclass">S</str>
<str name="producttype">GRD</str>
<int name="relativeorbitnumber">8</int>
<int name="lastrelativeorbitnumber">8</int>
<str name="platformname">Sentinel-1</str>
<date name="beginposition">2016-11-12T06:06:23.524Z</date>
<date name="endposition">2016-11-12T06:06:48.523Z</date>
<str name="size">1.64 GB</str>
<int name="slicenumber">11</int>
<str name="status">ARCHIVED</str>
<bool name="processed">false</bool>
</entry>
<entry>
```

sample of output which includes the additional unwanted lines:

```
<str name="filename">S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161113T055721_20161113T055746_002936_004FB6_2A93.SAFE</str>
<str name="identifier">S1B_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161113T055721_20161113T055746_002936_004FB6_2A93</str>
<title>S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF</title>
<str name="filename">S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF.SAFE</str>
```

`

I do not want lines that contain `S1B`or `identifier` or `title`. E.g. the actual type of output I want in my `s1_gg.txt` file:

```
<str name="filename">S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20161112T060623_20161112T060648_013905_01661B_ECEF.SAFE</str>
```

Comment: What is `grep "\S1A_\"` supposed to match? Esp. that `\S` there?

Comment: I'm absolutely confused about how you can get your output file from the `fileout` sample you showed us. None of the lines in the output are present in the `fileout`. Please show us a relevant part of your data presented in a working example.

Comment: I was trying to get only `S1A` rather than any line containing S, 1, A in any order/location on the line, that syntax is probably wrong but with just "S1A" I get the same result as above.

Comment: Is that XML? If so, you should use some XML-aware tool instead of `grep`.

Comment: It looks like .xml, it is a result of wget on schihub website as: `wget --no-check-certificate --user="username" --password="password" -O - 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/search?start=200&rows=100&q=footprint:"Intersects(55.84704,1.251517)"' >>`. Can you recommend an XML-aware tool?

Comment: using xml_grep I get `junk after document element at line 4295, column 0, byte 253812 at /usr/lib64/perl5/XML/Parser.pm line 187
 at /usr/bin/xml_grep line 128
 at /usr/bin/xml_grep line 128
<!-- error parsing file 'fileout' -->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several flaws in your script :

- `grep` hangs after its execution and has to be terminated by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Your quotation is very approximative. The behaviour of `\` is to escape the following character, treating it as a literal in the case of special characters or as a character class in case of normal characters.

  - you wrote `"\>` instead of `\">`. you escaped the letter `S` and the following `"` character when you wrote `\S\"`.
  - You should have wirtten : `grep "=\"filename\">" | grep "S1A_" | grep "GRDH" fileout >> s1_gg.txt`
- You pass your input file to your 3rd `grep` call.

  - You should have written :  `< fileout grep "=\"filename\">" | grep "S1A_" | grep "GRDH" >> s1_gg.txt`
  - This last correction gives you the right output and solves the hang of `grep`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful feedback. Do you know why the similar command `< GG_S1A.txt grep "=\"filename\">" | grep "S1A_" | grep "GRDH" >> s1_gg.txt` doesn't require/work with `-f` option to specify that it is a file?

Comment: the `<` is used for file [redirection redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). It is implied that the redirected element is a file.